# Get spreadsheet id or url from the spreadsheets name

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have multiple named spreadsheets in a folder on google drive. How would I get their id or url by passing one of the names to a function?

I can get the file using DriveApp, but I dont know how to get the id from that.

```
function getFile(name)
{
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('id');
  var file = folder.getFilesByName(name);
  //get file id
}
```

Is there a way to get the id or url using DriveApp or SpreadsheetApp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `folder.getFilesByName(name);`potentially retrieve more than one file (has it's name say it- *getFile**s***) so it give you a **file iterator** that you need to parse with a **while loop**.
If you are absolutely sure that there is at least one file with that has the name, you can avoid the loop with a little dirty code like this:
`var file = folder.getFilesByName(name).next();`
and then retrieve the id with:
`var id = file.getId()`

**-- EDIT:**
If you are not sure to retrieve a file (You don't know if it exist or has the right name....) you'll need to check the result of the file iterator.
Instead of writing :
`var file = folder.getFilesByName(name);`
prefer to write:
`var files = folder.getFilesByName(name); // you could have zero or more than one file`
And then you can do a **while loop** if you believe there is more than one file with that name:

```
var out = [];
while(files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  out.push(file.getId());
  Logger.log(file.getId());
}
return out;
```

or if there is only one or zero file a simple if will do the job:

```
if (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  Logger.log(file.getId());
  return file.getIt(); // eventually
}
else {
  Logger.log("there is no file with that name");
  return "no id"; // eventually
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end.` , when I add the `.next()` and `var id = file.getId()`. What would the while loop look like? `while (file.hasNext()){get file id}` ?

Comment: That mean there is no file with that name (0 result ) I'll update the post to show you what to do